# Laravel Inertiajs Vue3 - Default selected value in dropdown

Tags: laravel, select, vuejs3, inertiajs

I'm playing around with vue3, inertiajs and laravel. I'm trying to understand something. In the below example, the initial value is not shown when using the `Select.vue` component, the last option (test) is the selected one. For the `<select v-model="form.test">` it is shown initially.

When inspecting the dropdowns they both are showing this though:

```
<option v-if="false" value="1">Some Value</option>
<option v-if="true" value="2">Another Value</option>
<option v-if="false" value="3">test</option>
```

I'm wondering what I am missing here..

This is my `Test.vue` component:

```
<template>

    <form @submit.prevent="submit">
        <select v-model="form.test">
            <option v-for="option in options" :key="option.id" :value="option.id" :v-if="option.id == initial" selected>{{
                    option.name
                }}
            </option>
        </select>

        <Select name="test" placeholder="Select Something"
                v-model="form.test" :options="options"/>

    </form>

</template>

<script setup>
import {useForm} from "@inertiajs/vue3";
import Select from "./Components/Forms/Input/Select.vue";

let options = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "Some Value"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Another Value"},
    {"id": 3, "name": "test"},
]

let initial = 2

defineProps({
    options: Array
});

let form = useForm({
    test: initial
});
</script>
```

And here is my `Select.vue` component:

```
<template>
        <label :for="name" class="col-lg-3 col-form-label">{{ name }}:</label>
    
            <select :name="name" :id="name" @change="emit('update:model-value', $event.target.value);" class="form-select" :class="error ? 'is-invalid' : ''">
                <option :value="null" hidden>{{ placeholder }}</option>
                <option v-for="option in options" :key="option.id" :value="option.id" :v-if="option.id == modelValue" selected>{{
                        option.name
                    }}
                </option>
            </select>

        </div>

    </div>

    {{ modelValue }}

</template>

<script setup>
defineProps({
    name: String,
    placeholder: String,
    options: Object,
    error: String,
    modelValue: String
});

let emit = defineEmits(['update:model-value']);
</script>
```

Comment: you can also change `:v-if` to `v-if` and it should work

Comment: Yeah I tried but I got an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I am doing it wrong it seems. Using the following worked:

```
:selected="option.id === modelValue"
```